# get last seven month list and last seven weeks list in python

Tags: python, django

I am new to python and django framework so please help me.
if present week number is 41 (10/10/2019) so last seven weeks means 40, 39,38,37,36,35,34 etc if present week number is 1 then need last year weeks numbers and also for months.
This all for me to get the last 7 weeks day and the last 7 months data 
Thank you

Comment: Post the code for your data source. Is it a model? An API?

Comment: this is the model                                                                                            
class NewArticle(models.Model):                                                                                          user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)                    keyword = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)        
 article_length = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=SUB_TYPE_CHOICES, default='400')                               
last_updated = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True,blank=True)

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```
In [5]: now = datetime.datetime.now()

In [6]: for i in range(1, 8):
   ...:     date = now - datetime.timedelta(weeks=i)
   ...:     print(date.isocalendar()[1])
   ...:
40
39
38
37
36
35
34
```

Comment: I need get data of each week (weeks number) from model

Comment: I got the answer Thank you @kevin

Comment: if i want get previous year weeks when the present week is less then 6 then how ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function below. You need to run the function with year, month & date (example `func(2018,12,6)`)

```
from datetime import date,timedelta

def func(yr,mon,dt):
    entry = date(yr, mon,dt)
    for i in range(1, 8):
        back_week = entry - timedelta(weeks=i)
        print('Week ' + str(back_week.isocalendar()[1]))
        back_days = entry - timedelta(days=i)
        print('Date '+ str(back_days.day))
        print(back_days.strftime('%A'))
        print(back_days.strftime('%B'))

func(2018,12,6)
```

**Output** change the code as needed.

```
Week 48
Date 5
Wednesday
December
Week 47
Date 4
Tuesday
December
Week 46
Date 3
Monday
December
Week 45
Date 2
Sunday
December
Week 44
Date 1
Saturday
December
Week 43
Date 30
Friday
November
Week 42
Date 29
Thursday
November
```